# Jenkins Integration with S3 for hosting React Application

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, amazon-s3

I am new to Jenkins, I have a React js application where it is hosted on Amazon S3. So I wanted to make a CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins. Most of the part is done but I am stuck at the last step. Connecting Jenkins with Amazon S3. I am able to get the updated code from Github and generate a build file in the Jenkins server. Now I wanted to move this new build file to AWS S3 for static website hosting.

I hosted my Jenkins server on EC2 Instance.

Can anyone help me to achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solution to implement

1.configure aws cli  on Jenkins Slave or Master where you are running build and in jenkins Step Run command to copy those file to s3bucket

ex: aws s3 cp

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

2. You can use s3 publisher plugin to copy artifact to bucket

Comment: Hey, Shubham I tried both second solution doesn't suit my use case I am going with the first one. Thanks for the response.

Comment: If you feel 1st option suits your  use case sure go with it.

Comment: aws s3 cp jenkinsFolderLocation s3bucket This worked for me.